# Best way to sort the results of multiple join statements

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure if the best answer to my question is found in php or how I organize my results. I have the pages of my site orginized in the database in three tables pages, components, scripts. i select the page data with a statement as such:

```
SELECT pages.id AS pageID, pages.view AS pageView, pages.accessLev, scripts.scriptPath, components.componentPath
FROM  `pages`
LEFT OUTER JOIN scripts
ON scripts.page_id = page.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN components
ON components.page_id = pages.id
WHERE pgs.pageName = 'home'
```

the pages my have varying numbers of both scripts and components, multiple one to many relationships.

if a page has two scripts and one component i get two rows in the result one for each script.

```
pageID  pageView  accessLev  scriptPath  componentPath

2       homeView  0          script1     component1
2       homeView  0          script2     component1
```

if it has 2 compontents i get 4 rows:,

```
pageID  pageView  accessLev  scriptPath  componentPath

2       homeView  0          script1     component1
2       homeView  0          script1     component2
2       homeView  0          script2     component1
2       homeView  0          script2     component2
```

My question i guess is ether how best should i order the result of the mysql or should i be useing php to deal with the organization of the results.

Comment: You should do it in the way that suits you best. :-)

Comment: i was thinking mostly that i must be doing something wrong because i have repeating results

Comment: But why is that wrong?

Comment: seems if the results didnt repeat that it wound be more efficient

Comment: less to extracting needed results

Comment: Without seeing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) together with the desired result, we can't really know what you have, what you want, and why the two don't match up! That said, on the face of it, there's nothing wrong with your query per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have one result per page you must change your query to something like this:

```
SELECT 
    `pages`.id AS pageID, 
    `pages`.view AS pageView, 
    `pages`.accessLev, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`scripts`.scriptPath SEPARATOR ',') AS scriptsPath, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`components`.componentPath SEPARATOR ',') AS componentsPath
FROM `pages`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `scripts`
ON `scripts`.page_id = `pages`.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `components`
ON `components`.page_id = `pages`.id
WHERE `pages`.pageName = 'home'
GROUP BY `pages`.id
```

Comment: You *can* do something like that, but there's certainly *must* about it! ;-) Personally, I think GROUP_CONCAT (and CONCAT) is a silly function and should be avoided!

Comment: why do you feel that they should be avoided?